# Inequalities relating the cardinality of finite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Take $A$ and $A$ to be finite sets whose cardinalities are denoted $|A|$ and $|B|$ respectively. Are the follow two inequalities about the union and intersection of $A$ and $B$ true?

$$\mathrm{max}(|A|,|B|) \leq |A \cup B| \leq |A| + |B|$$
$$0 \leq |A \cap B| \leq \mathrm{min}(|A|,|B|)$$

If these inequalities are true are the upper and lower bounds optimal?

Comment: Yes. Take $A=B$ and $A= \emptyset$ and you will see that these bounds are optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both inequalities are true for simple reasons:

$A$ and $B$ are subsets of $A \cup B$ thus $|A|, |B| \le |A \cup B|$. And $$\begin{align*}|A \cup B| &= |A \setminus B| + \underbrace{|B \setminus A| + |A \cap B|}_{\le |B|} \\
& \le |A| + |B|
\end{align*}$$

Now, since $A \cap B \subseteq A, B$, we also get
$$
|A \cap B| \le \min(|A|, |B|).
$$

However, I don't know what you mean when you ask whether these bounds are 'optimal'. Do you mean that equality holds? If so, the answer is no and I'll leave it to you to find counterexamples (there are plenty easy counterexamples).

Comment: Define an optimal lower bound as the greatest lower bound and an optimal upper bound as the lowest upper bound.

Comment: Optimal with respect to which restrictions? If there are no restrictions, then the only optimal bounds are the exact values, i.g. $|A \cup B|$ and $|A \cap B|$ respectively.

Comment: You are correct I need to specify restrictions. Say that $A$ and $B$ may be disjoint, joint or equal.

Comment: Those are not restrictions relevant to your question. I also don't know what it means for two sets to be 'joint'.